# What is the best way to do a flicker-free animated C# custom control?

Tags: c#, animation, controls, doublebuffered

I am currently creating a custom control that needs to handle animation in a C# project. It is basically a listbox that contains a fixed number of elements that are subject to move. An element (another user control with a background image and a couple of generated labels) can move upwards, downwards or be taken out of the list.

I would like to create animated movement as the elements get moved around within the container custom control but it seems to me that moving controls around using lines such as

```
myCustomControl.left -= m_iSpeed;
```

triggered within a timer event is flickery and has a terrible rendering, even with double buffering turned on.

So here's the question : **What is the best way to achieve a flicker-free animated C# control?** Should I just not create custom controls and handle all of the drawing within a panel's background image that I generate? Is there a super animation method that I have not discovered? :)

Thanks!

Comment: What GUI toolkit are you using?

Comment: He mentions C#, so I think we're likely talking about .Net Windows Forms.  I think DoubleBuffering is the answer, but I'm not recalling the specifics at the moment.

Comment: right, I am using regulat .net windows forms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your best bet for flicker-free animation is to do the painting yourself (use the Graphics object in the Paint event handler) and use double-buffering. In your custom control you will need code like this in the constructor:

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | 
    ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor,
    true);
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar discussion took place this morning on this question. [visual c# form update results in flickering.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181374/visual-c-form-update-results-in-flickering) so I will be lazy and give the same answer I gave there:

You could try to call **this.SuspendLayout();** before you start your move and **this.ResumeLayout(false);** when you have finished moving all of the controls. In this way all controls should draw at once and you should have less of a flicker.

*On a side note I have tried to reproduce this here at work, but seem to be failing. Can you give some more sample code that I can fix maybe?*

Answer (score 1):

[See How to double buffer .NET controls on a form.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76993/how-to-double-buffer-net-controls-on-a-form/77233#77233)

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to get flicker-free animation is to implement double-buffering.  Take a look at this Code Project article

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/flickerFreeDrawing.aspx

Minimizing calls to paint until you are ready is also a good idea.