# What could cause Double Buffering to kill my app?

Tags: c#, components, gdi+, double-buffering

I have a few custom (winforms) components that draw to the screen using GDI+.

To prevent flickering on repaint, I decided to enable double buffering, so I added a line to my constructor:

```
public ColourWheel()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DoubleBuffered = true;
}
```

Which works fine on this component (ColourWheel). When I add the same line to the constructor of either of my other two (similarly structured) components, I get a couple of strange  symptoms:

1. When I try to run a form with the component on, I get an Argument Exception on `Application.Run(new Form());`.
2. If I switch to design mode, I get an error about the component having an unhandled exception to do with a parameter.

It doesn't seem to matter whether I turn double buffering on one or all of them, it still works on the ColourWheel, but not the others.

*For the record, I've also tried a few other [double](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77233/50151) [buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/181384/50151) techniques.*

What could be causing double buffering to work on one component, but not others?

---

**EDIT:** Here's the exception detail from the run-time symptom:

> System.ArgumentException was unhandled   Message=Parameter is not
>   valid.   Source=System.Drawing   StackTrace:
>          at System.Drawing.Graphics.GetHdc()
>          at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphics.RenderInternal(HandleRef refTargetDC, BufferedGraphics buffer)
>          at System.Drawing.BufferedGraphics.Render()
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
>          at TestForm.Program.Main() in D:\Documents and Settings\Tom Wright\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\ColourPicker\TestForm\Program.cs:line 18
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

---

**EDIT 2:** The OnPaint handler from one (the more complicated) of the two components that are causing problems:

```
private void ValueSlider_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
       using (Graphics g = e.Graphics)
       {
           g.DrawImage(this.gradientImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, paintArea.Width, paintArea.Height));
           if (this.showmarker)
           {
               ColourHandler.HSV alt = ColourHandler.RGBtoHSV(new ColourHandler.RGB(this.SelectedColour.R, this.SelectedColour.G, this.SelectedColour.B));
               alt.Saturation = 0;
               alt.value = 255 - alt.value;
               using (Pen pen = new Pen(ColourHandler.HSVtoColour(alt)))
               {
                   pen.Width = (float)MARKERWIDTH;
                   g.DrawRectangle(pen, 0 - pen.Width, this.brightnessPoint.Y - MARKERWIDTH, this.paintArea.Width + (pen.Width * 2), MARKERWIDTH * 2);
               }
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you overriding OnPaint() in the offending controls? If so, what does that look like?

Comment: @roken I've editing my question to include my OnPaint handler.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You aren't supposed to dispose the `Graphics` object loaned to you during the `Paint` event, and that's what your `using` block improperly does.

The symptom is that the next time the `Paint` event fires, you get the same `Graphics` object back, but it is no longer bound to an in-memory `HDC`, causing `Graphics.GetHdc()` to fail as seen in your stack trace.

1. It's possible that it outlives a single `Paint` event (and this is very likely the case with double-buffering, although it's also possible with single-buffering if the `CS_OWNDC` window style is set).
2. There can be more than one handler for the `Paint` event.

So, event handlers should not call `Dispose` on the `Graphics` objects or allow a `using` block to do so.  Instead, the .NET framework cleans up resources as appropriate after `Paint` event handling is complete.

Comment: It worked for over a year then when I moved the user control class to  its own file started throwing the error OP here got. What you suggested worked - C# can be really weird sometimes!

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up, quite confusing on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-draw-an-outlined-shape?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8): _You should always call Dispose on any objects that consume system resources, such as Pen and Graphics objects._

Comment: @yano: Or course that only means the ones that YOU created.  Destroying objects that you borrow is very unkind to the real owner.

Comment: You deserve a couple of freaking beers, my friend. Well explained.

Comment: Came here to learn from the real source of the issue. Thanks @ben.

Answer (score 1):

You should test this on another machine to see if it's just your computer or not. For the most part, this shouldn't happen as a result of double buffering, but check to see if you are disposing any elements you shouldn't be in the Paint event or doing anything in the code that would have issues if done twice.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to dispose the `Graphics` object given to you during the `Paint` event.

Comment: @ben is right. Don't do a 'using' on 'g', as this will dispose the Graphics object when you exit that scope, but you aren't the'owner' of that object.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was doing `using (Graphics g = e.Graphics) { }`. Removing this was the key.