# When setting DoubleBuffered = true in subform, System.ArgumentException gets thrown in Program.cs (System.Drawing.dll)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am attempting to resolve some flickering issues in the Paint event by setting `DoubleBuffered = true` in a form that gets opened when the user clicks a button in the main form. However, just as the new form loads I get the exception in Program.cs

```
"System.ArgumentException occurred in System.Drawing.dll"


"System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'"
```

in the Program.cs file

I can confirm that the Paint method does not get called when the error pops up, and the error seems to occur just as the form's constructor is completed.
I'm setting `DoubleBuffered = True` in the Designer properties.

First form calling second form (Form1.cs)

```
if(toggleButton())
            {
                int numThreads = Int32.Parse(numeric_threads.Value.ToString());


                List<Section> sections = new List<Section>();
                sections.Add(new Section(0, 0, prevScreen.Bounds.Width, 100, checkbox_UseAudio.Checked, false, Int32.Parse(numeric_horizontalLEDs.Value.ToString()))); //Top
                sections.Add(new Section(0, prevScreen.Bounds.Height - 100, prevScreen.Bounds.Width, 100, false, false, Int32.Parse(numeric_horizontalLEDs.Value.ToString()))); //Bottom
                sections.Add(new Section(0, 0, 100, prevScreen.Bounds.Height, false, true, Int32.Parse(numeric_verticalLEDs.Value.ToString()))); //Left
                sections.Add(new Section(prevScreen.Bounds.Width - 100, 0, 100, prevScreen.Bounds.Height, false, true, Int32.Parse(numeric_verticalLEDs.Value.ToString())));//  Right
                dial = new LEDSimulate(pathScript, pathPython, formInst, sections, combo_monitor.SelectedIndex, numThreads);
                dial.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                button_flag = true;
                //Kill all the threads by closing
                dial.Close();
            }
```

Second form that gets opened form first form and results in the error (LEDSimulate.cs)

```
        public LEDSimulate(string pathScript, string pathPython, Form1 formInst, List<Section> sections, int mon, int numThreads)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            instance = this;

            this.TransparencyKey = (BackColor);
            this.sections = sections;
            this.procs = new List<Process>();
            this.formInst = formInst;

            //Initialize timer to tick every 30 seconds to update UI
            timer_updatePaint.Interval = 33;

            //Load with dummy data to update later
            Pen dummy_pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0, 0));
            foreach (Section s in sections)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i<s.subSections; i++)
                {
                    paintList.Add(new PaintForm(dummy_pen, 0, 0, 0, 0));
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Finished adding and starting");
            timer_updatePaint.Start();
            //-----Once this is done, the error occurs------
        }
```

Program.cs

```
static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1()); //Error pops up on this line
        }
    }
```

```
        private void timer_updatePaint_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Refresh();
        }

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;  // Turn on WS_EX_COMPOSITED
                return cp;
            }
        }
```

Comment: _timer_updatePaint_ Can we see the Tick ?

Comment: @TaW Added it. It only contains Refresh() to call the Paint, but this function does not get called before the error occurs

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, go to Debug->Exceptions and mark System.ArgumentException to break when the exception is thrown. That will catch the exception when it happens and not when it is handled.

Comment: @o_weisman After enabling this, it still seems to break exactly on that line (Application.Run(new Form1())) with no new information (I'll update OP for something I forgot to say though)

Comment: Do you have an OnPaint handler in your code and are you disposing one of its arguments like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134181/what-could-cause-double-buffering-to-kill-my-app ?

Comment: The other thing you have to do is Tools > Options > Debugging > General, untick "just my code".

Comment: @o_weisman Many thanks! I guess I was googling the wrong thing when trying to figure out what was wrong.
I did dispose of the Graphics object (using (var gfx = e.Graphics)) in the OnPaint handler. Removing it worked. I had not realized that after the handler is called, there is some backwork being done that still requires the object.

Comment: Glad to be of assistance :)

Comment: @o_weisman, yes... Disposing control graphics was the problem, thanks