# select items from listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, selectedindexchanged, indexoutofboundsexception

What i'm trying to do is select an item in my listview, and it works! That is it works once, the first time a select an item it go's well, the second time a get an argument out of range exception on features[0].SubItems[1].Text; on the zero.

this is what i have:

```
private void listViewFeatures_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection features = listViewFeatures.SelectedItems;
    string feature = features[0].SubItems[1].Text;
    BL_AddReport addReport = new BL_AddReport(this.databaseConnectionString);

    Dictionary<string, bool> pictures = addReport.GetpicturesFromFeature(feature);

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, bool> pic in pictures) 
    {
        if (pic.Value) {
            pictureBoxCar.Image = Image.FromFile(pic.Key);
        }
        else 
        {
            pictureBoxEquip.Image = Image.FromFile(pic.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Why not implement a simple `if` statement to make sure that `features.Count > 0`? All problems gone...

Comment: Please show the code on your Page_Load event handler. It may be that you are reloading the data on the load.

Comment: @Alex: Why do you assume this is an ASP.NET project? Could be Windows Forms...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - You are right, i should not have assumed that. But, if it is, it would be the right question to ask.

Comment: @Alex: Why? What would happen there?

Comment: it is a windows application, no asp.
a if statement doesn't help ether, it is only the first time it works, the rest gives a null

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar - If it was a asp.net, i think the load page happens before the selectedindexchanged event and if he relaods the data for the listview it might end up without any selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm betting you'd get this exception if you clicked off of the listview as well.

Remember that this event is for selection changes.. which may mean that something was selected and now nothing is. In fact, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86793/how-to-avoid-thousands-of-needless-listview-selectedindexchanged-events) an event is fired once for every thing that is selected. Take a look at that link for more information and designs around this problem if that is the case for you.

Otherwise just check to make sure that your "features" variable has anything inside of it before indexing into it