# In C# Forms How to Trap or Isolate when a Listview box is done updating with multiple selections?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, events, multipleselection

The app I am working on allows the user to select multiple items in a listView box using mouse clicks or keyboard , standard windows selection stuff, the trouble I am having is figuring out a way to know when the listview box is done updating the selections so I can run a routine on the **final selections**.
Both the events listView1_SelectedIndexChanged and  listView1_ItemSelectionChanged fire multiple times with more then one item selected which I suppose is expected behavior. I have tried  listView1_MouseClick which actually works as a final selection(s) entry point but then I am not sure how to handle keyboard selection in the same way as the mouse click event which doesn't involve the ItemSelectionChanged or index changed events.
There should be a simple way to do this I am just not finding it with the available events for this control. The below screen shots show the events fired with a typical selection "2" was already selected to start. As you can see the SelectedIndexChanged event fired one time for each new selection I need to determine when the control is done updating the selections. The selections can be 1 to 100's if not thousands.

[image: Events Output][image: Selections Box]

Comment: On the mouse/key up?

Comment: Can't you add a Button, or similar, that your Users have to push to confirm the selection they've made?

Comment: Questions: How do you as a human know when the `ListView` box is done updating selections? What's the visual or physical cue that we're trying to respond to? For example, does this multiple selection occur with a SHIFT-CLICK mouse action? To me this seems really doable, but there's a missing puzzle piece. What I'm wondering is if you just need some kind of watchdog timer (e.g. resets to a new 0.5 s delay every time `SelectedIndexChanged` fires) to let the events settle out for a half-a-second or so and then respond when the WDT finally runs to completion.

Comment: I thought of using a timer but the app generates a set of bit maps to visually display address labels so the complete selected set is needed.  the cue is the user is done selecting or the user changes the selections .  For now I am just going to use the mouse click event to move forward and will try to figure out the keyboard selection later or just require the user to use the mouse. I just wish there was a way to short circuit the SelectedIndexChanged  event to skip the firing for each selected item .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86793/how-to-avoid-thousands-of-needless-listview-selectedindexchanged-events?rq=2  I think Amir's async solution will work for me , seems to be firing only once with my data set ...